# Asynchronous update Android context menu

Tags: android, asynchronous, contextmenu

Word up, I need to update a context menu for a widget (listview in this case).

The items for the menu need to come from a call to a web service. If the web service call is made synchronously on the main UI thread then this works.

However due to fact that I'm calling a web service it needs to been done asynchronously via an AsyncTask or similar to avoid ANRs etc. This asynchronous update of the menu via menu.add() within the onCreateContextMenu doesn't work, i.e. asynchronous calls to menu.add() don't result in the context menu being displayed. Also note the async menu updates are done on the UI thread via the onPostExecute of an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 2):

All Ui updates have to be done on UI thread. So you will have to post a runnable onto Ui thread. 
Something like

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       //DO UI update here 
    }
});
```

Or you will have to call publishprogress() in doinBackground function of Asynctask and then do Ui work on [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29)(). 
If the Ui update can wait you should do it in [OnPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29)

Comment: Thanks nandeesh, however I'm already essentially doing this on the onPostExecute method of an AsyncTask which puts the update back on the ui thread for me. Would've been good if the problem was that simple ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to those that have provided answers, I may have to leave this for now with a somewhat half baked solution. For those reading this that are experiencing the same problem, my current solution uses the openContextMenu(View view) method in the activity to call back to the onCreateContextMenu. A simple boolean state flag determines whether to do the async call or populate the menu with the data from a previous async call. This design feels a bit awkward and fragile to me but works.

Answer (score 0):

Save the information, you get from the web-service in the activity. Then in onPrepareContextMenu() use this information to update the menu. onPrepareContextMenu() is called before the context menu is displayed. OnCreateContentMenu() is only called once for every activity instance.

Comment: thanks stefan, there doesn't seem to be an onPrepareContextMenu that I can override in the Activity. I have used the strategy you have described above for the options menu previously via onPrepareOptionsMenu but can't find the onPrepareContextMenu method you mention. On which class or interface is the onPrepareContextMenu defined?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, there no onPrepareContextMenu(), I had the options menu in mind. onCreateContextMenu is called before the menu is to be shown unlike onCreateOptionsMenu, which is only called once.